# What is the life of cell-free genetic circuits?

Tags: genetics, synthetic-biology

Can genetic circuits be tested in a cell-free environment? What would be their life if we keep them at room temperature?

The circuits which are composed of DNA-based components are commonly referred to as genetic circuits. By testing, I meant to say to test its behavior i.e. applying input signals (perhaps proteins) to see if it generates an output signal (another protein, may be fluorescent protein).

By life, I meant to say, for how long such a circuit (containing strings of dna) can survive at normal room temperature.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What do you mean by a "genetic circuit" and what kind of testing are you interested in doing? What do you mean by "life"? Are you sure these are biological questions? Please note that questions should be clear and **demonstrate** prior research. In addition, separate questions should be posted separately. ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Quick search for "cell-free genetic circuit" gets [this article](https://www.pnas.org/content/100/22/12672) as first result. They give time for which the transcription and translation reactions run. I wouldn't call the reactions life.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. 
@tyersome: The circuits which are composed of DNA-based components are commonly referred to as genetic circuits. By testing, I meant to say to test its behavior i.e. applying input signals (perhaps proteins) to see if it generates an output signal (another protein, may be fluorescent protein). 

By life, I meant to say, for how long such a circuit (containing strings of dna) can survive at normal room temperature.

Comment: @BagiM: Thanks for reaching out. I am not calling the reactions a "life". As I said in previous comment, I meant to say for how long such a system can be usable.

Comment: @HasanBaig Comments are meant for suggesting clarifications and such; it's better to edit your question in response rather than replying as a comment. Questions and answers are meant to be long-lived, comments are not.

Comment: Also it's up to you to write clearly, not to expect others to interpret your writing to discover your intent.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: And I thought people are already aware of genetic circuits. This is the reason why I did not explain it in details. Next time I will try to explain in more details.

Comment: The word "survive" does not really clarify the previous word "life". The reaction mix is not living at any point in time. Are you asking at what time does the production of fluorescent protein stop? Are you asking how long it takes for reactants (ATP) to be consumed? Are you asking how long it takes for the individual components of reaction to degrade (eg. RNA-polymerases to loose function)? For the first two questions, If you have read the article I linked in my previous coment you could have find the answer yourself.